# Do ESOP company employees need to fill out Schedule C?

Tags: united-states, taxes, business

I work at an ESOP so technically I am one of the "owners" of a business.

This resulted in my W-2 having the entry in box 12a as "C XXX" where XXX is an amount less than $1000.

Can I just enter XXX in box 12 of my 1040 or do I have to fill out a whole Schedule C?

The Schedule C form is very complicated and asks all kinds of questions about the financials of my company about which I know nothing.

---

Further research indicates that code C means that this amount is "Group Term Life Insurance", which apparently gets added in to Line 1 already, so my guess is I can ignore the amount in the box. Is that right? What is the purpose of breaking out this income in box 12?

Comment: Owning a few shares of stock does not require you file as an owner, just as an investor.

Answer (score 2):

If the company pays for Group Term Life Insurance, some of that premium payment may be taxable.  If memory serves, that's what's included in W-2 Box C.

W-2 Box C has no bearing on Schedule C.